# What are the differences between the various boost ublas sparse vectors?

Tags: c++, data-structures, boost, ublas

In `boost::numeric::ublas`, there are [three sparse vector types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_sparse.htm).

I can see that the `mapped_vector` is essentially an `stl::map` from index to value, which considers all not-found values to be 0 (or whatever is the common value).

But the documentation is sparse (ha ha) on information about `compressed_vector` and `coordinate_vector`.

Is anyone able to clarify? I'm trying to figure out the algorithmic complexity of adding items to the various vectors, and also of dot products between two such vectors.

A very helpful answer offered that compressed_vector is very similar to [compressed_matrix](http://www.guwi17.de/ublas/matrix_sparse_usage.html). But it seems that, for example, [compressed row storage](http://www.netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node91.html#SECTION00931100000000000000) is only for storing matrices -- not just vectors.

I see that `unbounded_array` is the storage type, but I'm not quite sure what the specification is for that, either. If I create a compressed_vector with size 200,000,000, but with only 5 non-zero locations, is this less efficient in any way than creating a compressed_vector with size 10 and 5 non-zero locations?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace matrix with vector and you have the answers

http://www.guwi17.de/ublas/matrix_sparse_usage.html

Comment: @mohawkjohn  for the product you probably want compressed_vector

Comment: Okay, so this doesn't completely answer my question after all. For example, the compressed_matrix is stored using compressed row storage. But the compressed_vector couldn't be stored that way, could it?

Comment: @mohawkjohn it certainly can, all it does is store contiguous blocks of nonzero elements.